# How can i programmatically change magento media storage?

Tags: php, magento

How can i programmatically change magento media storage ?

Hi, i want to change magento media storage from cli script:

i case to do that im trying to set configuration like this:

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode(Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage::XML_PATH_STORAGE_MEDIA, 1);
```

it changes media storage from filesystem to database, but it doesnt work.

can anyone help me? what i ahve to to to just change media storage system? i dont want to synchronize files just to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vardius,you can do this using below code

```
$Config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
/*
*turns notice on
*/
$Config ->saveConfig('default/system/media_storage_configuration/media_storage', "1", 'default', 0);
```